# Django UniqueConstraint case insensitive and unaccented

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I know I could get unique case insensitive field by using
`from django.contrib.postgres.fields import CICharField`, but I couldn't get it work by something like

```py
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["name__unaccent"],
                name="unique name",
            ),
        ]
```

I have `UnaccentExtension`, but this still throws error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Group has no field named 'name__unaccent'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it somehow possible achieve, what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `__unaccent` accessors or the like in the `fields` parameter, because it only accept bare field names (which internally maps to real database columns).

I'm unsure about what you ask for is possible or not, as `constraints` have to resolve into valid SQL constrains, and I don't see any way of doing such a thing.

One other option is to handle this at form validation (where performing a query using `__unaccent` to see if any entries already exist is trivial).